# Connect to an open network with Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I looked into different posts or sites to help me to do an app which can connect to an open wifi network (name: OpenWrt). I can't connect with the app unless I manually do it before. Could someone please look into this and help me? :) I should maybe add the network to the networks list on the phone, but I'm not sure how to do it, if it is the problem.

Thank you!

```
package com.example.wificonnect;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Définition du réseau wifi auquel on se connecte
    String networkSSID = "\"OpenWrt\"";

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Configuration des paramètres de connexion
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

    conf.SSID = networkSSID;                                                
    conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    // Activation du wifi si pas encore activé
    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

  }
}
```

I also add permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

EDIT:
Should I add something like this just after the wifi activation?

```
int networkId = -1;
    if(wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks() != null) {
        for (WifiConfiguration configuredNetwork : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
            if (conf.SSID.equals(configuredNetwork.SSID)) {
                networkId = configuredNetwork.networkId;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Network already registered : " + networkId);
            }
        }
    }

    if (networkId == -1) {
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Network registered : " + networkId);
    } else {
        wifiManager.updateNetwork(conf);
    }

wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
```

Comment: What is your `netId` after calling `addNetwork`?

Comment: Hm I thought it was necessary to add the network with an int and then enable it with this int.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but what does addNetwork return? Is it -1?

Comment: Then your wifi config misses something. If `addNetwork` returns -1, it failed.

Comment: Could you see my edit pls? Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

### First get the ScanResult object for the open network.

> Then you can use this method. That I have created for you.

```
public void connect(Context context, ScanResult scanResult){

    WifiManagersingletonWifiManager = (WifiManager)context
                                      .getApplicationContext()
                                      .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    configuration = new WifiConfiguration();
    configuration.SSID = scanResult.SSID;
    configuration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    int networkId = singletonWifiManager.addNetwork(configuration);

    if(!singletonWifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        singletonWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

    singletonWifiManager.disconnect();
    singletonWifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId,true);
    singletonWifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

### Also dont forget to declare permissions in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

## Useful Resource:

You can check out my [Repository on Github](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu) for more related code.